# Updating dbcopy database when parent MapReduce View Changes

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a database called "development-records" that has a MapReduce view with a "dbcopy" declaration that creates a view in a new database called "development-chained".

When we make an update the view in "development-records", we do the usual steps of: 
1. Create a duplicate copy of the design document that we want to change, for example by adding _OLD to its name: _design/fetch_OLD.
2. Put the new or 'incoming' design document into the database, using a name with the suffix _NEW: _design/fetch_NEW.
3. Query the fetch_NEW view, to ensure that it starts to build.
4. Poll the _active_tasks endpoint and wait until the index has finished building.
5. Put a duplicate copy of the new design document into _design/fetch.
6. Delete Design Document _design/fetch_NEW.
7. Delete Design Document _design/fetch_OLD.

The problem is that the documents specified in the dbcopy database "development-chained" don't seem to be updated -- all the old records stay.  Is there a way to trigger the dbcopy database to perform the MapReduce again?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to the [official Cloudant documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/offerings/whatsnew.html#breaking-behavior-changes), "The dbcopy feature can cause problems under some circumstances." Use of this feature is strongly discouraged, and has otherwise been removed from the documentation. I hope knowing that helps a little. The new documentation is hard to find.